# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ObjectId

Tags: python, mongodb, list

I have a list of user `user_list=["5c471d607f","5c63e9e46a","5c63e9e44e"]` I am trying to insert it into mongodb to insert it inro mongodb my code is:

```
for i in range(0,len(user_list)):
    collection_4.update_one({'user_id':ObjectId(user_list[i])},{'$set':{'products': temp_list }},upsert=True)

This is giving me error, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ObjectId
```

While i am able to insert it when i tried:

```
collection_4.update_one({'user_id':ObjectId("5c471d607f")},{'$set':{'products': temp_list }},upsert=True)
```

What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: Try: `collection_4.update_one({'user_id':ObjectId(str(user_list[i]))},{'$set':{'products': temp_list }},upsert=True)`

Comment: Still same error

Comment: You have a typo in your `user_list` a missing `"` from the last element

Comment: This: `for index, item in enumerate(user_list):
    collection_4.update_one({'user_id': ObjectId(index)}, {'$set': {'products': temp_list}}, upsert=True)` ?

Comment: I have edited the typo in my question but in my actual list there is nothing wrong i check the type of each element in user_list and all of them are str only

Comment: Have you accidently done user_list[ObjectId(i)] ?

Comment: No, I get my user_list from pandas dataframe column . and the type of that column is category. i converted the value in string

Answer (score 0):

You must have another error in your script somewhere. I can reproduce your error by doing the following:

```
from bson import ObjectId
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l[ObjectId('5c91ec870000000000000000')]
```

gives:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ObjectId
```

Are you sure you're not attempting to slice a list anywhere using an `ObjectId`, rather than using an index?

You might need to print more code because your current example seems to be ok.

One other improvement that @DirtyBit picked up, you can use `enumerate` to iterate over a list whilst tracking the index:

```
for i, item in enumerate(user_list):
    collection_4.update_one({'user_id':ObjectId(item)},{'$set':{'products': temp_list }},upsert=True)
```

But then again, you don't require the index, so you could also just do:

```
for item in user_list:
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
for i in range(0,len(user_list)):
    myid = user_list[i]
    collection_4.update_one({'user_id':str(myid)},{'$set':{'products': temp_list }},upsert=True)
```

Comment: how can the same error occurs if there is no ObjectId in for loop ?